# I have a for loop that print's numbers. But I don't want it to print a few numbers

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So i have a for loop that prints numbers from 3333 to 9999 in **JavaScript**. I want it so that when my for loop prints the numbers, it checks for every number if it contains the number 0, 1, 2 or 5. This is the code I have written till now but it still doesn't work. Hope you can help me.

```
    for (let i = 3333; i <= 9999; i++) {
        if (i === 1) {
            continue;
        } else if (i === 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (i === 5) {
            continue;
        } else if (i === 2) {
            continue;
        } else {
            console.log(i)
        }

    }
}

printNum();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (let i = 3333; i <= 9999; i++) {
    if (i.toString().includes(0) || i.toString().includes(1) ||i.toString().includes(2) || i.toString().includes(5)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

the following code will work fine. It converts the number to a string and checks if it contains 0,1,2 or 5 and if it finds such a number it just continues without printing it to the console

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was so helpful, it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with regex would look like this

```js
for (let i = 3333; i <= 9999; i++) {
    if (/[0125]/.test(i)) {
        continue;
    } else {
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```